# How to test your sinatra app's javascript with jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, sinatra, asset-pipeline

I'm having an hard time setting up jasmine to load my javascripts from my sinatra app. Basically I'm using the asset-pipeline (yes, I have it in the sinatra app in dev), and using angular. Ideally I could let the app run somewhere in a port while I would apply my tests directly, as getting fixtures in such an interactive app will make my eyes rain.

So, bottom line: how can I make jasmine load an asset-pipelined non-rails app?